# Adding application icons to Artful Aardvark Activities and dock

Tags: gnome, gui, dock

How can I add one of my applications to the "Activities"? How can I pin it to the dock?

Comment: Hit F2, start typing name of app , when the icon comes up right click it, add to favorites.

Comment: No luck, F2 does nothing. I am running Artful Aardvark as a VM on a Windows 10 host, so, maybe that's why.

Comment: Guess it is Alt-F2 see https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/CheatSheet . Not had to create a desktop file manually to add yet.

Comment: On the application, right click, add to favorites. I assume it is the same for dock, I dont use a dock . Custom apps are different of course.

Comment: @Panther I think that's what OP meant, custom apps. Installed apps usually create their desktop files automatically and thus they are visible in "Activities" by default. As you suggested one just needs to right click and "add to favourites" to add them to the dock. For custom apps one needs to create a desktop file first and then it would be visible in Activities.

Comment: @pomsky - add all that as an answer, installed / default apps ... add to fav ... custom apps create a .desktop ... details or link to similar answer here.

Comment: @Panther The proposed duplicate does more or less  fine, I think.